# Vagrant multi-machine provisions every machine

Tags: ruby, vagrant

If I try `vagrant up secondmachine` against this Vagrantfile below, Vagrant will only create one Ubuntu VM named "secondmachine". However, Vagrant will still try to run the "firstmachine" script on it.

How can I convince Vagrant to only provision machines it's actually brought up, and/or that have been specified on the command-line? Is there a right way and a wrong way to loop through multiple machine definitions?

```rb
# coding: utf-8
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

nodes = [

  {
    :name      => "firstmachine",
    :autostart => false,
    :box       => "centos/7",
    :provisioners => [
      {
        :script  => "cat /etc/redhat-release",
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    :name      => "secondmachine",
    :autostart => false,
    :box       => "ubuntu/trusty64",
    :provisioners => [
      {
        :script  => "apt-get update",
      },
    ],
  },

]

Vagrant.require_version ">= 2.0.2"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  nodes.each do |node|

    # Will ignore any node without a name!
    next if node[:name].empty?

    config.vm.define node[:name], autostart: node[:autostart] do |machine|
      machine.vm.box = node[:box]

      node[:provisioners].each do |provisioner|

        config.vm.provision
          type: "shell",
          privileged: privileged,
          inline: provisioner[:script]

      end

    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that the provisioner is assigned to the config object, not the subsequent machine instances. In short, changing `config.vm.provision` to `machine.vm.provision` clears up the trouble.